# How to get all combinations of a string by removing 4 characters each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, combinations

I'm trying to create a function in JavaScript that for a given string will output all possible combinations by removing
ONLY 4 characters from the string each time. How i can output all the combinations?The length of starting string is dynamic.Thanks in advance.

**Note:**The order of removing 4 characters shouldn't be always consecutive

Example:

```
string:BmamdWRtaW51dGfVzZMI=  //B   m   a   m  d  W   R  t  a  W   5   1   d   G   f  V  z  Z  M  I  =
                             // 1   2   3   4  5  6   7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Want to print all possible combination like this:

```
 BmamdWRtaW51dGfVzZMI= (starting string)
-dWRtaW51dGfVzZMI=     (removed first 4 characters)
-BWRtaW51dGfVzZMI=     (removed 4 consecutive charaters start from 2th character)
-BmRtaW51dGfVzZMI=     (removed 4 consecutive charaters start from 3th character)
-BmataW51dGfVzZMI=     (removed 4 consecutive charaters start from 4th character)
-
-
```

Comment: Have you tried any particular approach so far?

Comment: Are the 4 characters always consecutive?

Comment: Thanks for replies. @Jean-Claude Colette the 4 characters shouldn't always be consecutive i want to print out all possible combinations.

Comment: @Jonas w.Thanks for reply. The string content and size is dynamic but I should only delete 4 characters each time. The characters on the string are not in in any order!

Answer (score 3):

Assume n the length of the string str

```
for (a=0; a<n-3; a++) {
    for (b=a+1; b<n-2; b++) {
        for (c=b+1; c<n-1; c++) {
            for (d=c+1; d<n; d++) {
                //delete the ath, bth, cth and dth charaters of the initial string
                result = str.substr(0, a)+str.substr(a+1, b-a-1)+str.substr(b+1, c-b-1)+str.substr(c+1, d-c-1)+str.substr(d+1);

                //and print the result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful if you really remove chars from strings step by step: the save way to do this is to first remove the char with the highest index, then the one before. Otherwise you have to correct the remainign indices.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Colette Thanks for example .Which variable is initial string and why you mentioned to delete 3 letters instead of 4?How to start deleting 4 characters from each combination of starting string ?For example for a string size of 21 how many combinations of 17 character string will be produced ?

Comment: str is the initial string, and I extract the substrings at the beginning, between each and the last.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode for a recursive function:

```
myFunction (charactersRemoved, remainingString, previousString):

if charactersRemoved === 4 then echo previousString + remainingString
return

foreach character in remainingString
remainingString -= character
myFunction (charactersRemoved + 1, remainingString, previousString)
previousString += character
endfor

endfunction

myFunction(0, string, '')
```